# RIP George A. Romero

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

George A Romero, best known for his seminal [Night of the Living Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dead_(film_series)) film series has died after a brief battle with lung cancer.

His work has had an incalculable influence on modern movie-making and he will be sorely missed by his legion of fans.

[image]